# UISplitViewController set in portrait mode

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

In ipad app I want to set UISplitViewController method set in portrait mode.(i.e Like Settings application in ipad)

I have created a SplitViewbased application .When i run the application in portrait mode it doesn't show the splitview when i change the orientation into landscape it shows the splitview.In portrait mode also there is a toolbar button name "Root List" When i click the button it shows popover view to split view.

I want to show splitview in portrait mode with two separte views each has navigation controller.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you will be able to do this with the UISplitViewController, you would need to build your own custom version of it which mimicked most of the normal behavior, but kept the table showing in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 5 the UISplitViewController will work in portrait mode. Look at the documentation for the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at Matt Legend's [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad).

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController)